# Can't reach field inside an object in my angular controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

I'm using a factory to get a television show from a database. I wanted to send just the episodes field from this object to a angular service but I keep getting undefined using dot notation and bracket notation. Can someone explain how to get this field.

Controller

```
angular.module('showApp.controllers', []).controller('ShowViewController', function($scope, $stateParams, Show, $http) {
  $scope.show = Show.get({ id: $stateParams.id }); //Get a single show.Issues a GET to /api/shows/:id

  console.log($scope.show)
  console.log($scope.show.episodes)
})
```

Console Output

```
m
$promise:d
$resolved:true
__v:0
_id:"581a5b82ff9e9f10f22afff7"
airs_on:Array[1]
episodes:Array[11]
genre:Array[3]
network:"Netflix"
poster:"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTk5NTk1Mzg3Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDAyNzY3OA@@._V1._CR25,3,1010,1343_SY1000_CR0,0,752,1000_AL_.jpg"
program_time:60
rated:"TV-MA"
streams_on:Array[3]
title:"Black Mirror"
yearBegin:2011
__proto__:Object

undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wait for results by:

```
$scope.show.$promise.then(function(show) {
  console.log(show.episodes);
})
```

you should call the service in the `then` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a timing issue. There should be a callback from the http get request, at which time $scope.show is valid - you should do your console logging in the callback

Comment: Async problem, okay, I'm very new to learning angular or mean stack programming in general so I'm not sure how to send the result of the get to another service, this is the factory I created from an example 
angular.module('showApp.services', []).factory('Show', function($resource) {
  return $resource('https://television-catalog-rawlejuglal.c9users.io/api/shows/:id', { id: '@_id' }, {
    update: {
      method: 'PUT'
    }
  });
});